# outputting numbers in order using loops in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

The output should look like this with the numbers switching every time it increments

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
```

And mine looks like this which is nothing like the one above

```
1
11
111
1111
11111
111111
```

I don't know how to change the numbers every time x increments in my code. I have my code below but can anyone fix this for me or help me fix it.

```
public class Loom {

    public void numbersloop() {

        int v = 1;
        char z = '1';
        while (v <= 6) {
            int x = 1;
            while (x <= v) {
                System.out.print(z);
                x += 1;
            }
            v += 1;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Loom n = new Loom();
        n.numbersloop();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to increment `z`:

```
v += 1; z += 1;
```

***P.S.** It could be much more simpler if you use `for` loop:*

```
public void numbersloop() {
    for (int row = 1; row <= 6; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < row; col++)
            System.out.print(row);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Allow me to correct your English. _It could be much simpler if you use `for` loop_

Answer (score 0):

you should change your nested loop, so instead of printing the value of z, it prints the value of x (the variable that changes periodically).

Answer (score 0):

**Since Java 11 you can use String repeat()**

See usage String repeat() for this type of output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(i).repeat(i));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
```